# Order Collection of Objects by Ascending Date(s) from Current Date

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

In PHP, I have an object array and I need to sort it starting with the most recent date from today and going out. The dates are stored as strings with only month and day.

I can use usort with function like below to get it sorted chronologically but I'm struggling with how to get it to sort when compared against today's date.

```php
function date_sort($a, $b) {
  return strtotime($a->bday) - strtotime($b->bday);
}

usort($users, "date_sort");
```

The original array looks like this:

```php
$users = array(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Tim
            [bday] => September 13
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Scott
            [bday] => November 8
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Bob
            [bday] => October 13
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Dan
            [bday] => February 2
        )
    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Jack
            [bday] => July 11
        ) 
)
```

If today is October 8, I need the sorted array to look like:

```php
$users = array(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Bob
            [bday] => October 13
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Scott
            [bday] => November 8
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Dan
            [bday] => February 2
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Jack
            [bday] => July 11
        ) 
    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Tim
            [bday] => September 13
        )
)
```

Comment: Calculate the difference of "now - a" and "now - b" (or vice versa) and compare these...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your comparison function, you compare the timestamps from `strtotime()` to the timestamp for the current date.  Since by default it will use the current year for days without years, if the timestamp is less than the current timestamp, add a year.  Do this for both `$a->bday` and $b->bday`.  Then do your comparison.

```
function date_sort($a, $b) {
    if(strtotime($a->bday) < strtotime(date("Y-m-d")))
    {
        $adate = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($a->bday)) . " +1 year");
    }
    else
    {
        $adate = strtotime($a->bday);
    }
    if(strtotime($b->bday) < strtotime(date("Y-m-d")))
    {
        $bdate = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($b->bday)) . " +1 year");
    }
    else
    {
        $bdate = strtotime($b->bday);
    }
  return $adate - $bdate;
}
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/45071b77e770a72f55c7751da823495cd9606e35)

Another option (perhaps better performance-wise) would be to iterate through the array, compare to the current day, adjust the dates as needed, and then call `usort()` on the adjusted array.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting function can be something like this:

```
$now = new DateTime();

usort($users, function($a, $b) use ($now) {
    $aDate = new DateTime($a->bday);
    if ($aDate < $now) {
        $aDate->add(new DateInterval('P1Y'));
    }

    $bDate = new DateTime($b->bday);
    if ($bDate < $now) { 
        $bDate->add(new DateInterval('P1Y'));
    }

    return $aDate > $bDate;  
});
```

Of course, converting to `DateTime` objects can be performed once in a separate `while` loop so as to reduce redundancy.

Sample fiddle https://3v4l.org/u3U80.